# Finding Normal Vector for this Integral (confusion between two different ways).

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Find $\iint(x^2+y^2)dS$,
>  $S: x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ 
> while $z\ge \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

I know that, in order to solve this integral, I need to find normal vector $\vec N$ and find $|\vec N|$, so I can move to double integral and solve. 
But, I've seen two ways of finding the normal vector, and I'm not sure which one I can use. 
Here's the first way: 
Basically to $F(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0$, and then
$\vec \nabla F=2x+2y+2z$ 
would give the normal. I can understand this way and been using it for a long time.
 
The second way: (Which my TA used while solving): 
$z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$, and so the normal is: 
$\vec N=(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}},\frac{y}{1-x^2-y^2},1)$, using the formula $(-f_x,-f_y,1)$ as a normal for function $z=f(x,y)$. 

Now both these ways seem reasonable to me, but I can see that they both give a different normal and that bugs me, because I've thought I will get the same answer. 

I would appreciate any feedback or explanation to strengthen my understanding of these two ways and what is happening here in this question. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a square root missing in your second $N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both $\langle 2x,2y,2z \rangle$ and $\left \langle \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}},1 \right \rangle$ are normal to this surface*.  You can see that because you can get the first one from the second one by multiplying by $2\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$. Consequently you can in principle obtain a normal to the surface either way.

However, the normal that is used in the formulas for surface integrals via double integrals is not just a normal chosen randomly among all the normals. It is a normal whose magnitude describes the relationship between area on the surface and area in the parameter domain. Accordingly, you are really stuck with using $\mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_v$ as your normal when computing surface integrals via double integrals**. The $\langle -f_x,-f_y,1 \rangle$ formula is a special case of this in the case where the surface is parametrized as $\mathbf{r}(x,y)=\langle x,y,f(x,y) \rangle$.

* Technically the second one isn't defined at $(0,0,1)$ which is a point on this surface, but that's just one point so it doesn't mess anything up.

** When you get to oriented surfaces, the correct normal may be either $\mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_v$ or $-(\mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_v)$, depending on the orientation of the surface, the parametrization that you chose, and the order you put the parameters in. In the situation of oriented surfaces, you just want the normal you use in the calculation to point in the direction of the normal of the surface, so you force in a minus sign if it is needed to make that happen.

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many normal vectors.  Your second one is the *unit* normal (upward).  If you divide your first one by its own length, you get the second one.  Compare the final integrals in both methods and you can see where that length appears (or hides) in each one.

Answer (score 1):

The value that you have from your first approach is not correct as you must map surface area element to the area element in XY plane (even though it is indeed a normal vector to the sphere). So you will need to make the z-component $1$.

$(2x, 2y, 2z)$ should be written as $\left(\dfrac{x}{z}, \dfrac{y}{z}, 1\right)$

You are doing surface integral of a scalar function and you are using projection in XY-plane. So you can either apply the surface area formula directly,

$dS = \sqrt{1 + \left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2} \ dA$

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 \implies \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} = - \dfrac{x}{z}, \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y} = - \dfrac{y}{z}$

That leads to $ \ dS = \dfrac{dA}{z} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}} \ dA \ $ (as $z \geq 0)$

which is what you did in the second approach.

Or you can parametrize the surface as,

$f(x,y) = (x, y, \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$

$f_x \times f_y = \left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}, \dfrac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}, 1\right)$

So, $|f_x \times f_y| = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}$

Comment: I still don't get the idea of why it isn't correct, what I did gives me the normal vector too doesn't it?

Comment: @Pwaol it is a normal vector. In fact take any point $(x, y, z)$ on the sphere and center is $(0, 0, 0)$ so it is easy to see that $(x-0, y-0, z-0)$ is a normal vector. But you are doing surface integral of a scalar field (not vector field) so all that matters is how you map surface area element to area of the projection in XY plane.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite get it, I can understand why the second way is correct and the formula you provided I've seen it's proof. But I still made this mistake and I can't get why I can't take the normal vector I found using the first way, like what does the normal vector found using the second way differ from it?

Comment: @Pwaol does the edit clarify? My point is that you must choose the normal that maps surface area element to the area of the projection in XY-plane

Comment: Yes now I understand what you were trying to say, it was a little hard, but when I read Ian answer, things got clear and I can understand you now, Thanks alot for the help!

Comment: Thinking about it, will using spherical coordinates with $R=1$ work here? if I know that area element of a sphere is $R^2sin(\phi)d\theta d\phi$? (I know the normal might be hard, but in theory, does this work?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127117/discussion-between-math-lover-and-pwaol).